# Jekyll — Loop through posts with title and number

Tags: loops, count, jekyll, liquid

I'm building a simple blog using Jekyll. I'm looping through all of my posts which works a treat. However, I'd like to add a number marker to each post. For example the first post would be marked with a 1, second with a 2... and so on.

My current loop likes like this:

```
<ol class="post-list">
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li class="post-item">
      <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
        <div class="post-info">
          <p>Post #1</p>
          <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

I understand I need to add a count to this loop but I'm unsure how.

Adding the following to my loop seems to make sense:

```
{% for num in (1...n) %}
```

But I'm not sure how to use this with my existing loop.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 5):

In each liquid loop you have a counter out of the box : `forloop`

Change : `<p>Post #1</p>` for : `<p>Post #{{ forloop.index }}</p>`

[Documentation here](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to count them automatically you can simple add the variable to your posts:

```
---
number: 1
---
```

Than call it via

```
{{ post.number }}
```

Comment: Sorry for mentioning you before @DavidJacquel, I really didn't think it was bad, I just thought you could help him out.

Comment: No problem. The community is supposed to help people, and djacquel is just a small part of the community.

Comment: This works unless you have hundreds of posts and don't want to go through them all...